# Read from InputStream in Swift from Java Server

Tags: java, swift, inputstream, outputstream

as the title says, I'm trying to read from an InputStream in Swift. I'm new to Swift so I'm having some troubles regarding how to read from the InputStream a message sent from the Java Server.

Java Server Code:

```
byte[] toSend = sec.initiateDH;

out.writeInt(toSend.length);
out.write(toSend);
```

Swift Client Code

```
init(_ ipAddress: String, _ port: Int, _ textEncoding: String.Encoding) {
    super.init()
    Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: ipAddress, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
    
    
    inp!.open()
    out!.open()

    
    print("Connection Established")
   
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to initiate a DH key exchange. The Swift client sends their public key, and in return, the server is supposed to send back theirs. It does send, but I'm having trouble reading from the InputStream. First, the server sends the size and only then sends the byte array itself. Server uses DataOutputStream for writing.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well , u not send to mach information about what ur problem but I suppose that you want read an php file from sever so there is tow part :
part one reading the php file in the swift part you need to add this code in viewDidload() func :

```
let URL_USER_data = "https://www.ursite.net/infoinputstream.php"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //Sending http post request
       Alamofire.request(URL_USER_data , method: .get).responseJSON
       {
           response in
           //printing response
           print(response)
           //getting the json value from the server
           if let result = response.result.value {
               //converting it as NSDictionary
               let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
               //displaying the message in label
               self.bytetext.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "byte") as! String?
               self.sizetext.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "size") as! String?
           
             
           }
       }
   }
```

don't forget to import Alamofire at the beginning of ur code.
and the php part "infoinputstream.php"  or what ever ur php code supposed to be something like ..

```html
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';


        $query1="SELECT* FROM data";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
          while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) ){
          
            $$response=$row1['byte'];
             $$response=$row1['size'];
      
             
          }
          echo json_encode($response);   
          ?>
```

Hope it's help ..

Comment: Hello there, I'm not trying to read a php file. I create a public key for Diffie Hellman exchange on a Java server. That creates an encoded byte array that I need to send to the Swift client. My problem is, I send the value from the Java Server to the Swift Client, but I have no idea nor understand how to read it from the InputStream in Swift. So I was hoping someone could lend a hand or explain how it works because I really can't make it work. Thank you for the effort though!